# Advice for adding pumpkin to pancakes?

Tags: pumpkin, pancakes

free pancake recipe (see below) that requires applesauce and would like to know how I could best incorporate canned pumpkin, to make some really yummy pancakes for the holidays. Can I just replace the applesauce and add water until it is the right consistency?

> 1 cup wheat flour
>
> 1/4 teaspoon salt
>
> 1 1/2 teaspoons baking powder
>
> 1/2 cup soy milk or applejuice
>
> 1 beaten egg (or substitute)
>
> 1/2 teaspoon vanilla
>
> 1 1/4 cups applesauce
>
> 1 teaspoon cinnamon

Alternative formulations also appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: as you can see in our FAQ (http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq), recipe requests are off topic and this question will likely be closed.  What you can do is provide us your recipe for pancakes that you usually use and ask for seasoned suggestions on incorporating pancakes.  You could also try finding a pumpkin pancake recipe and asking us for suggestions on how to make it over-the-top good.  It'd be great if you edit your question to one of these on-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @justkt, I have edited the question; please let me know if you have any further suggestions.

Comment: these are dairy free buttermilk pancakes?  I don't see buttermilk in the recipe.

Comment: @justkt Thanks for the pointing this out. I have removed the buttermilk from the title as I did from the recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excellent [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/why-can-applesauce-be-used-in-place-of-oil/6875#6875) to the question [Why can applesauce be used in place of oil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/why-can-applesauce-be-used-in-place-of-oil) points out that one of the key reasons for using applesauce in quick bread type recipes such as pancakes is the pectin.  Pumpkin [also](http://www.foodnavigator.com/Science-Nutrition/Pumpkin-pectin-may-offer-novel-gelling-opportunities) contains pectin.  Therefore pumpkin should provide a similar effect on your recipe as the applesauce.

What the pumpkin puree won't provide is the sugar that applesauce provides.  You will likely want to up the sugar provided by your recipe to account for this, unless you routinely use unsweetened applesauce.  The water content between pumpkin puree and applesauce will also be different, as will the exact proteins.

I would suggest starting with a *one to one* replacement of pumpkin for applesauce for a very pumpkin-y taste, but you will have to experiment.  You will also want to add sugar to taste.  If you want a more subtle flavor, consider substituting only part of the applesauce with pumpkin.

Comment: thanks! I replaced the applesauce with pumpkin, added some extra water, and they were delicious