# Do I need to freeze this puree and syrup?

Tags: food-safety, syrup, oranges

Related questions: [What causes a cake to sink in the center?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/what-causes-a-cake-to-sink-in-the-center) and [How can I get the maximum flavor from orange peels?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41114/how-can-i-get-the-maximum-flavor-from-orange-peels)

I ended up simmering the zest of 6 oranges (peeled with a vegetable peeler, so there was still a small amount of pith) without rinsing at all. When they were tender, I added the supremed segments of those oranges and simmered the everything for another half hour. I strained the syrup and gave the solids a bit of a whir in the food processor.

I have just enough puree for one more cake, and this lovely orange syrup. I used a lot of sugar. I can't guesstimate how much sugar because I just kept adding it until I got the level of sweetness I want, but the viscosity of the strained syrup is like Aunt Jemima pancake syrup.

I'll bake the cake again in 3 or 4 weeks. Will the puree and syrup last that long in the fridge? Or should I freeze it?

Comment: Better safe than sorry.   You haven't measured the absolute sugar or acidity levels.  Freezing it will do no harm.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ  Add that as an answer and I'll upvote it. Barring another great answer within a week or so and I'll accept it. In the meantime, I'm freezing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been said:

> Better safe than sorry. You haven't measured the absolute sugar or acidity levels. Freezing it will do no harm. –  [SAJ14SAJ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/20183/jolenealaska) [Jan 29 at 1:47](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41551/do-i-need-to-freeze-this-puree-and-syrup#comment58466_41551)

I'm definitely not an expert with baking, but I've worked with fruits in other contexts. The only time I would be worried about freezing would be if I added oil, like for a marinade or such. In your context I think freezing is fine, and sounds like it would be a convenient way to make larger batches to reuse throughout the year.

*PS: That puree sounds awesome, I might have to try that to marinate some chicken or pork chops!*