# Using pectin as a fat replacement

Tags: substitutions, apples, pectin

I make pectin stock from apples for use in jams and jellies, and I have lots of it. I would like to try using this stock as a fat substitute in baking, similar to replacing some of the fat in recipes with applesauce. Has anyone tried this, and what advice do they have to offer.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/why-can-applesauce-be-used-in-place-of-oil

Answer (score 4):

I found a study done in Korea in 2010 that said pectin can replace shortening in cookies and therefore, they concluded other baked goods.  The ideal amount was 30% replacement saying the texture was actually better and the cookies were more moist.  They don't recommend going higher than 30% as a 40% difference changed the structural integrity in a "negative" way!  It looks really interesting!  Here is the website I found:
http://www.foodnavigator.com/Science-Nutrition/Pectin-rich-ingredients-show-fat-replacing-potential
Good Luck!

Comment: I'd love to see some more information about these "pectin-enriched materials" and how they're made.  I'm guessing it's more complicated than just powdered pectin.